# .NET Roslyn : runtime configuration

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am going to develop some rules with the Roslyn code analyzer. This rule is to control the access of a namespace. 
Example, the DAL can use only the core. If the View use the DAL, I want a warning.

I use the template "Analyzer with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)" in 'Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition' to generate the plugin.

I have made some test and it works fine. However the rule is written at hard in the code. I don't know how configure the rule in the runtime.
The best will be a configuration file in the solution or the project.

Can you give me some example?

Thank.

Resume of solution :

1. Add the file in Visual Studio in the project analyzed.
2. Open the .csproj with a editor modify the item group of configuration file.

   `<None Include="test.txt" />`
   ->
   `<AdditionalFiles Include="test.txt" />`

[Example to read the file](https://github.com/tmeschter/roslyn/blob/b21fbca8535341013bd9388f88c71bac980f7f48/src/Samples/CSharp/Analyzers/CSharpAnalyzers/CSharpAnalyzers/AdditionalFileAnalyzers/SimpleAdditionalFileAnalyzer.cs)!

Comment: Seems like a overkill, only to prevent co-workers to break some application design. Instead separate View and DataAccessLayer in different projects

Comment: It is also a overkill to separate a small project in few projects. My need is limited the interaction between module in the small project. NDepend can check this, but not when I write my code.

Comment: Is having separated code files for every class or separating 100 lines method in small methods which doing only one thing, is this a overkill in case if you have only two classes and two methods? Adding new project in the solution is very cheap process in compare with time you spend on this question. Based only on information, that you have DataAccess layer, View layer and Core layer I think the project is big enough to separate layers to different projects even every layer has only one code file.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear. This example is overkill, but the question is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add analyzer runtime configuration via [`AdditionalFiles`](http://source.roslyn.io/#MSBuildFiles/C/ProgramFiles(x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin_/amd64/Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets,234) items in the `.csproj`. They get expanded into [`/additionalfile:<path>`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.CommandLine.UnitTests/CommandLineTests.cs,7357) command-line options for the compiler. In VS "15" preview you can do that from the UI:

[image]

Setting this adds the following to your .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AdditionalFiles Include="test.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Your Analyzer can accesses them via [AnalyzerOptions.AdditionalFiles](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/DiagnosticAnalyzer/AnalyzerOptions.cs,7197d586b9314062,references), available in [CompilationStartAnalysisContext.Options](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/DiagnosticAnalyzer/DiagnosticAnalysisContext.cs,291).

Comment: Sound good, but when I add the tag, the project can't be open. Can you add a example of .csproj (or just the 'AdditionalFileImtes' tag)?

Comment: @VernouCédric see picture

Comment: Is there any option do add UI that allows to configure analyzer?