# Configurable .NET Analyzer

Tags: roslyn, visual-studio-2017, roslyn-code-analysis

I created a DiagnosticAnalyzer + CodeFixProvider that checks all public properties/methods of a class if they have *virtual* modifier (because of NHibernate proxies). But this should only be done on classes that implements some interface. For now I hardcoded those interfaces into analyzer code. What is the best option to make them configurable via configuration file included in project? Example configuration file:

```
<VirtualAnalzyer>
    <ValidTypes>
        <ValidType>IEntity</ValidType>
        <ValidType>IVersionedEntity</ValidType>
    </ValidTypes>
<VirtualAnalzyer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using [additional files](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Using%20Additional%20Files.md). Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575138/net-roslyn-runtime-configuration/37576991#37576991) on how to include AdditionalFile in csproj.